# How to get a table for all the factor variables having less than a specific number of levels?

Tags: r, apply

So I'm trying to make tables for all the factor variables with less than 3 levels in my data frame.

My current method is as follows:

```
df=data.frame(a=1:10, b=as.factor(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))), c=as.factor(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,5),rep(3,2)))) ## Dataset

myfun = function(x) {
    if(is.factor(x) && levels(x) < 3) {
        table(x)
    }
}

tab = apply(df, 2, myfun)
```

While this is working, could I do the same thing using `lapply`?

Using on of the apply functions, we could do this:

```
myfun = function(x) {
    if(length(unique(x)) < 3){ table(x) } 
}
```

Comment: The example you showed are all numeric variables

Comment: @akrun im changing b and c to factor.

Comment: Please check the updated solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the example showed have no `factor` variables and are all numeric, we can loop through the columns with `lapply` and get the `table`  `if` the `length` of `unique` elements is less than 3 or `else` return NA.

```
lapply(df, function(x) if(length(unique(x)) < 3) table(x) else NA)
```

NOTE: Based on the OP's first example.

#### Update

If there are infact `factor` variables, it is not good to use `apply` as it converts it to a `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only `character` or `numeric` class thereby the `factor` column coerce to `character` and using `levels` will be useless on that case.  We can use `lapply` for that

```
lapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(x) & nlevels(x) <3) table(x) else NA)
```

Comment: Thanks i tried this lapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(x) && levels(x)<3){table(x)}) but it doesn't take levels function into consideration.

Comment: Got it i need to use nlevels instead of levels